# C++ - STL - Vector - Why there is no facility to indicate relocation_count in the vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

It is quite surprising that given that reserving size for a vector in anticipation helps improve the performance of the application and 
ensures that costly relocations do not occur when it gets filled 
to its capacity why there is no facility given to get a relocation_count 
at any given time , this may very much help programmer track optimal 
size to be allocated to vector in cases where the exact capacity may 
need to be determined from average over period of observations as
exact figure may not be known upfront.

Comment: You may wrap `std::vector::push_back()` into a free-standing function (template) and count it by yourself by comparison of old/new `std::vector::capacity()`.

Comment: This type of question of off topic on SO. The obvious answer is that this functionality requires an additional data variable w/o adding to the core functionality of `vector`. Anybody who really needs this functionality can easily generate their own extension of `vector` to this end.

Comment: The general answer to "Why is there not <feature>?" is that every feature starts out at [-100 points](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/), and only those things that hit positive figures have a *chance* of being implemented

Comment: What should the `relocation_count` be for a *copy* of a vector? what about a *moved-to* vector? should you be able to reset the count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count re-allocations of a `std::vector`, the `std::vector` (or at least the write access methods of it) might be wrapped into a helper class.

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename VALUE>
struct AllocCounter {
  std::vector<VALUE> &vec;
  unsigned n;

  AllocCounter(std::vector<VALUE> &vec): vec(vec), n(0) { }
  void push_back(const VALUE &value)
  {
    size_t old = vec.capacity();
    vec.push_back(value);
    n += old != vec.capacity();
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> values;
  AllocCounter<int> countAllocs(values);
  for (int i = 1; i <= 1024; ++i) {
    unsigned nOld = countAllocs.n;
    countAllocs.push_back(i);
    if (countAllocs.n > nOld) std::cout << 'R';
    std::cout << '.';
  }
  std::cout << '\n'
    << "Number of (re-)allocations: " << countAllocs.n << '\n';
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
R.R.R..R....R........R................R................................R................................................................R................................................................................................................................R................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................R................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Number of (re-)allocations: 11
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/773a2ef082dbda04)</kbd>

This sample is rather a proof of concept as it doesn't consider `std::vector::emplace()`, `std::vector::resize()`, etc.

Btw. if `std::vector::push_back()` is called directly the counting is by-passed (and may "overlook" re-allocations).

Using a custom allocator could solve this limitation.